# How to handle Undefined offset error for odd array items?

Tags: php

I have an array with 13 items as below:

```
$skus = array(
            "PK 800G",
            "CH 800G",
            "910G",
            "400G",
            "1.5KG",
            "1KG",
            "A 1KG",
            "E 1KG",
            "D 1KG",
            "2 G.",
            "ESSENCE",
            "N 800G.",
            "H 800 G"
);
```

My problem is if I have 13 items in the array, following code give me error:

```
(1/1) ErrorException
Undefined offset: 13
```

But if I remove single item from the array and make it "12" then it works fine. 
I am sure it is because of the loop. But I am not able to figure it out.

```
$total = count($skus);
$skuKeys = array_keys($skus);
$iter = ceil($total / 4);

for ($n = 0; $n <= $iter; $n++) {
    $row = ["G", "A"];
    $row2 = ["", ""];
    for ($j = $n*4; $j < 4 * ($n+1); $j++) {
        if ($j == 2) {
            $row = array_merge($row, ["RT + PK","","","","","",""]);
            $row2 = array_merge($row2, ["TY", "LY", "YTD", "TY", "LY", "MTD", ""]);
        }
        $row = array_merge($row, [$skuKeys[$j],"","","","","",""]);
        $row2 = array_merge($row2, ["TY", "LY", "YTD", "TY", "LY", "MTD", ""]);
    }
}
```

Can anybody please help me?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems. First, in your computation of `$iter`, you need to use

```
$iter = floor(($total - 1) / 4);
```

otherwise for a `$total` which is a multiple of 4 you will do one too many iterations through the loop, and since you are using `$n <= $iter` in your outer for loop you need to use `floor` instead of `ceil`, otherwise you will again do one too many iterations through the loop.

Your second issue (and the one causing the error message) is that in your inner for loop you are not checking that you are still within the bounds of the array. So after the `for`, you need to add a check for that:

```
if ($j == $total) break;
```

So your code should change to:

```
$iter = floor(($total - 1) / 4);
for ($n = 0; $n <= $iter; $n++) {
    $row = ["G", "A"];
    $row2 = ["", ""];
    for ($j = $n*4; $j < 4 * ($n+1); $j++) {
        if ($j == $total) break;
        if ($j == 2) {
            $row = array_merge($row, ["RT + PK","","","","","",""]);
            $row2 = array_merge($row2, ["TY", "LY", "YTD", "TY", "LY", "MTD", ""]);
        }
        $row = array_merge($row, [$skuKeys[$j],"","","","","",""]);
        $row2 = array_merge($row2, ["TY", "LY", "YTD", "TY", "LY", "MTD", ""]);
    }
}
```

I suspect that you have other issues within your code (unless you are doing something with `$row` and `$row2` in the loop that you haven't shown us), as you are overwriting the values of `$row` and `$row2` on each pass through the outer loop. However these fixes will resolve your current issue.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are working on `index` of an `array` which is 1 less then the length of the array. TRY ...

```
$total = count($skus);
$skuKeys = array_keys($skus);
$iter = ceil($total / 4);

for ($n = 0; $n < $iter; $n++) {
    $row = ["G", "A"];
    $row2 = ["", ""];
    for ($j = $n*4; $j < 4 * ($n+1); $j++) {
        if ($j == 2) {
            $row = array_merge($row, ["RT + PK","","","","","",""]);
            $row2 = array_merge($row2, ["TY", "LY", "YTD", "TY", "LY", "MTD", ""]);
        }
        $row = array_merge($row, [$skuKeys[$j],"","","","","",""]);
        $row2 = array_merge($row2, ["TY", "LY", "YTD", "TY", "LY", "MTD", ""]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I still have same issue

Comment: And what is the difference between my code and yours solutions . They look same

Comment: `for ($n = 0; $n < $iter; $n++) {` instead of `for ($n = 0; $n <= $iter; $n++) {`

Comment: You may try using `intval()` instead of `ceil()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$skus = array(
            "PK 800G",
            "CH 800G",
            "910G",
            "400G",
            "1.5KG",
            "1KG",
            "A 1KG",
            "E 1KG",
            "D 1KG",
            "2 G.",
            "ESSENCE",
            "N 800G.",
            "H 800 G"
);

$total = count($skus);
$skuKeys = array_keys($skus);
$iter = round($total / 4);

for ($n = 0; $n < $iter; $n++) {

    $row = ["G", "A"];
    $row2 = ["", ""];
    for ($j = $n*4; $j < 4 * ($n+1); $j++) {
        if ($j == 2) {
            $row = array_merge($row, ["RT + PK","","","","","",""]);
            $row2 = array_merge($row2, ["TY", "LY", "YTD", "TY", "LY", "MTD", ""]);
        }
        $row = array_merge($row, [$skuKeys[$j],"","","","","",""]);
        $row2 = array_merge($row2, ["TY", "LY", "YTD", "TY", "LY", "MTD", ""]);
    }

}

var_dump($row);
var_dump($row2);
```